# Get data from a web server in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asynchronous, httprequest

I have a very convenient way of getting data from a web server in my Android app, and would like to be able to duplicate that method for iOS.

In Android I have a Async Class that I call from other classes and it returns data from server when it has finished loading.

This is how that class looks like:

public class GetData extends AsyncTask, String, Void> {

```
public Context context;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;

public GetData (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
/**
 * Send the values in params to the server
 */
protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params) {

    String server = "mywebpage";
    HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(server);
    HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0]));
        HttpResponse rs=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = rs.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        is.close();
        publishProgress(sb.toString());

    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

}

If I want to use the GetData class I create a new instance of it like so:

new GetData(this.getActivity()) {

```
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... string) {
            result = string[0]);

        }
    }.execute(data);
```

I have been able to get and send data from within each viewController in iOS but I haven't been able to get a similar method to this one to work.

I have been trying to create a Class but I'm not sure how to call it with certain parameters and what subclass I should make GetData be of.

Is there any good way to do this in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the commonly used [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library. Here is an example of how to do a post:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Also, though I have not used it yet, it looks like you can use AFURLSessionManager to update progress in upload and download tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you make a connection without using a third party library:

[Creating a Connection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)